# Finding the smallest $n$ to modulo a set with no collisions

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Given a set of positive integers with no collisions (that is, every element is unique), $A = \{\ldots\}$, how can I find the smallest modulus, $n$, so that $B = A \pmod n$ has no collisions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We may just consider the difference set $D=A-A$, then take the least positive integer $n$ such that $n$ does not divide any positive element of $D$. Such $n$ is obviously a prime number.

Comment: Do you really mean $D=A-A=\emptyset$?

Comment: @MårtenW: the difference set $A-A$ is defined as $$A-A = \{a-b:a,b\in A\}.$$